# How do I check for capital letters in a string?

Tags: python

I have a string like AASaacwasA and I want to check whether any of it has a capital letter. What command can I use?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest thing I can think of:

```
test = "AASaacwasA"
not test.lower() == test
> True
```

Comment: True that, gonna edit, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> not 'AASaacwasA'.islower()
True
```

I guess more generally

```
>>> any(i.isupper() for i in 'AASaacwasA')
True
```

Comment: That would test that *all* characters are upper though, not *any* character

Comment: @DeepSpace `isupper` will only return `True` if all letters are uppercase, which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using regex:

```
test = "AASaacwasA"
if re.search(r'[A-Z]', test):
    print("Has capitals")
```